# Executing the DIV instruction in 8086 assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, division, x86-16

My program prints the msg3 statement (`PutStr msg3`), but does not proceed to the

```
DIV CX
```

instruction in my program.
Is there something I'm doing incorrectly with that register?
Or should the instruction be

```
DIV [CX]
```

instead or do I not have the compare and jump conditions set correctly?

```
prime_loop:
        sub AX,AX       ;clears the reg to allow the next index of the array
        sub CX,CX      ;clears counter to decrement starting from number of the value for array
        mov AX, [test_marks+ESI*4]      ;copy value of array at index ESI into reg
        mov CX, [test_marks+ESI*4]     ;copy value of array at index ESI into reg for purposes of counting down
    check_prime:
        dec CX 
        nwln
        PutStr msg3
        div WORD CX   ;divide value of EAX by ECX
        cmp DX,0     ;IF the remainder is zero
        je chck_divisor    ;check to see divisor 'ECX'
        sub AX,AX   ;else clear quotient register EAX
        sub DX,DX    ;clear remainder register
       mov AX,[test_marks+ESI*4]     ;move the number of the current iteration back into EAX
        jmp check_prime    ;start again from loop
    chck_divisor:
        cmp CX,1
        jne prime_loop     ;if the divisor is not 1 then it is not a prime number so continue with iterations
        PutInt AX     ;else print the prime_num
        PutStr
        inc ESI
        jmp prime_loop
    done:
        .EXIT
```

Comment: Your question is hard to answer without knowing the details of the `PutStr` and the `nwln`macros. Maybe they change some registers...

Comment: I don't understand why that should be the case. I only put those instructions there to track the progress of my program. My understanding is that those instructions only print a string and create a newline, not that it changes registers, at least according to the sample programs from my professors lecture notes.

Comment: I had included other "PutStr" instructions past the Div instruction to see if those would execute but they did not.

Comment: [DIV _CX_](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html) is actually the combined 32-bit value in _DX:AX_ divided by _CX_. If the result of the division doesn't fit in a 16-bit register you'll get an arithmetic exception (division exception). What happens if you zero out _DX_ before the division?

Comment: I have been testing with fairly small values for my array so I don't think that was the issue. Plus, I had initially used the EDX:EAX registers divided by ECX, to accommodate larger values but I was getting the same issue.

Comment: `PutStr` and `nwln` _are not x86 instructions_ , they are `macros` which _can do anything_! They can change _any_ register during their execution. Use a debugger to verify my claim - or - post their definitions if you really like to get an answer.

Comment: If you don't zero out _DX_ at the very least your division will be using the wrong value for the division.

Comment: What details about the PutStr and nwln would you need in order to determine if they would affect the register for the Div CX operation?

Comment: You really should be stepping through your code in a debugger to see what is happening

Comment: do you know if DOSbox has debugging tools? Its the program our professor has been telling us to use to run our programs.

Comment: Ask your professor what he recommends as tools to debug your code. If using DOSBox, I'd probably recommend Turbo Debugger. You'd have to download it off the internet. There are some source forge projects that include it but you can [download this tarball](http://www.capp-sysware.com/downloads/tasm.tgz) and extract it into your DOSBox directory. It provides Turbo Assembler (TASM.EXE) and Turbo Debugger (TD.EXE). If your professor doesn't know what you should use a debugger - they are frankly an idiot. Using a debugger should be part of the curriculum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some points about your code:

- If this is indeed **8086 assembly** then instructions like `mov AX, [test_marks+ESI*4]` that use scaled indexed addressing **simply don't exist**!
- The scale by 4 suggests that your array is filled with doublewords, yet you use just a word. This could be what you want, but it looks suspicious.
- Let's hope no array element is 1 because if so, then the `div cx` instruction will trigger an exception (#DE). Because you don't test the CX register for becoming 0.
- In the *check_prime* loop only the 1st iteration lacks the zeroing of DX in order to give a correct quotient.

The solution will depend on the targetted architecture *8086* or *x86*. Now your program is a mix of both!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that since DX is not zeroed before div, that you're getting overflow. I don't know how your environment handles overflow.